# I have a problem configuring SpringMVC, 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' is not assignable to 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet'

Tags: model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtNXT.png)

In the pom I configured like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDN9U.png)

Can you guys please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Your xml is for servlet version 4.x which is JavaEE and not JakartaEE. Fix your XML. Also remove the `javax.servlet-api` dependency and use the jakartaee version of that. ALl this being said please don't post code as images (or worse links to images), post them as code in your question instead.

Comment: I replaced the javax.servlet-api with the jakartaee version, but still reported an error.

Comment: Reading is really an art... You ignore the first sentence... **Your xml is for servlet version 4.x which is JavaEE and not JakartaEE**, upgrade your web.xml version as well.

Comment: That and your pom.xml contains an illegal char D in the xml.

Comment: Whoa, thank you. I'm sorry I didn't pay attention

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.